# Nginx keeps reopening logs

Tags: nginx

Here are some informations about nginx running on the cluster:

`nginx version: nginx/1.6.0
built by gcc 3.4.5 20051201 (Red Hat 3.4.5-2)
TLS SNI support disabled
configure arguments: --prefix=/home/work/local/nginx --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_realip_module --with-pcre=/home/work/download/pcre-8.35 --with-pcre-jit`

The question is that why the Nginx keeps reopening logs about every five minutes? I have checked all the CRON tasks, strangely, there is no CRON which will send reopen signal to Nginx passively.

These are some logs where i tail the `error.log` of Nginx

```
2015/08/18 15:42:20 [notice] 17496#0: signal 10 (SIGUSR1) received, reopening logs

2015/08/18 15:42:20 [notice] 17496#0: reopening logs

2015/08/18 15:42:20 [notice] 17497#0: reopening logs

2015/08/18 15:42:20 [notice] 17498#0: reopening logs

2015/08/18 15:42:20 [notice] 17500#0: reopening logs

2015/08/18 15:42:20 [notice] 17503#0: reopening logs

2015/08/18 15:42:20 [notice] 17501#0: reopening logs

2015/08/18 15:42:20 [notice] 17505#0: reopening logs

2015/08/18 15:42:20 [notice] 17504#0: reopening logs

2015/08/18 15:42:20 [notice] 17512#0: reopening logs

2015/08/18 15:42:20 [notice] 17515#0: reopening logs

2015/08/18 15:42:20 [notice] 17509#0: reopening logs

2015/08/18 15:42:20 [notice] 17506#0: reopening logs

2015/08/18 15:42:20 [notice] 17517#0: reopening logs

2015/08/18 15:42:20 [notice] 17507#0: reopening logs

2015/08/18 15:42:20 [notice] 17521#0: reopening logs

2015/08/18 15:42:20 [notice] 17519#0: reopening logs

2015/08/18 15:42:20 [notice] 17511#0: reopening logs

2015/08/18 15:42:20 [notice] 17518#0: reopening logs

2015/08/18 15:42:20 [notice] 17513#0: reopening logs

2015/08/18 15:42:20 [notice] 17510#0: reopening logs

2015/08/18 15:42:20 [notice] 17520#0: reopening logs

2015/08/18 15:47:21 [notice] 17496#0: signal 10 (SIGUSR1) received, reopening logs

2015/08/18 15:47:21 [notice] 17496#0: reopening logs

2015/08/18 15:47:21 [notice] 17498#0: reopening logs

2015/08/18 15:47:21 [notice] 17497#0: reopening logs

2015/08/18 15:47:21 [notice] 17504#0: reopening logs

2015/08/18 15:47:21 [notice] 17503#0: reopening logs

2015/08/18 15:47:21 [notice] 17501#0: reopening logs

2015/08/18 15:47:21 [notice] 17500#0: reopening logs

2015/08/18 15:47:21 [notice] 17518#0: reopening logs

2015/08/18 15:47:21 [notice] 17505#0: reopening logs

2015/08/18 15:47:21 [notice] 17521#0: reopening logs

2015/08/18 15:47:21 [notice] 17520#0: reopening logs

2015/08/18 15:47:21 [notice] 17519#0: reopening logs

2015/08/18 15:47:21 [notice] 17507#0: reopening logs

2015/08/18 15:47:21 [notice] 17509#0: reopening logs

2015/08/18 15:47:21 [notice] 17517#0: reopening logs

2015/08/18 15:47:21 [notice] 17506#0: reopening logs

2015/08/18 15:47:21 [notice] 17515#0: reopening logs

2015/08/18 15:47:21 [notice] 17513#0: reopening logs

2015/08/18 15:47:21 [notice] 17511#0: reopening logs

2015/08/18 15:47:21 [notice] 17512#0: reopening logs

2015/08/18 15:47:21 [notice] 17510#0: reopening logs
```

Grateful for your answering!

Answer (score 0):

`signal 10 (SIGUSR1) received` + http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.web.nginx.english/181 -> means something triggers log rotating... Nginx is not supporting that itself. Please see if you have logrotate running if so - please verify configuration.

Comment: Link to gmane.org is a dead link